# Using Heroku on free plan

Tags: heroku

Currently I'm testing the Heroku pipelines and I have 2 apps. The first app I deployed on staging as normal and have it working perfectly. Then to test the promote functionality I press the 'Promote' button, this copies the build across, but then the standard 'Something went wrong' page is shown in the browser. I noticed also that Postgres wasn't set up.

I cloned the first app locally from my remote git repo (bitbucket) and pushed from there to the production app. When I tried to open the app the same 'Something went wrong' page is shown in the browser.

The question then is, if I'm on the free plan, can I only spin up 1 dyno? If so, would this explain why I'm getting the 'Something went wrong' page when opening the production version? Would salesforce consider allowing it's free users to have 1 free dyno in each section of a user's pipeline? Can the developers at Heroku please make the error pages more informative instead of the same 'Something went wrong' displaying?

Thank you.

Comment: An unverified account can have 5 apps: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/302 You can run them all in parallel but it will drain your monthly dyno hours fast. You need to look in the logs to see a more informative answer to see what went wrong. The web page is publicly available and that's why there is little information.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not customer support for your favourite online hosting service

Answer (score 0):

You should have no problem running two apps on free dynos, at least for a while. You probably don't have enough in your monthly allowance to run them for a full month, but I don't think that explains your error. Check your [Heroku billing page](https://dashboard.heroku.com/account/billing) to see how many free dyno hours you have remaining.

You're probably just hitting the error because you haven't set up Postgres on your production app. To do that, run `heroku addons:create postgres`. You'd need to check your app logs (`heroku logs -t`) to be see the full error details.

I wrote a bunch more on maximizing Heroku's free dynos [here](https://railsautoscale.com/heroku-free-dynos), but as I said, I don't think that's your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Adam McCrea was right. Postgres needs to be setup first, although that wasn't how I solved the issue.

I cloned the repo for the staging app and then pushed into another app in production. When I promote any code changes it successfully copies in full.